# Creating an Item-based Recommender using Apache Mahout

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

I'm trying to use Apache Mahout to create an Item-based recommender that recommends back items based off of similar items that other users also have in common.

I start by creating a DataModel and then I've tried passing it into various different `ItemSimilarity` objects:

```
// Create data model
DataModel datamodel = new FileDataModel(new File("input.csv"));

// ItemSimilarity object
// ItemSimilarity similarity = new EuclideanDistanceSimilarity(datamodel);
// ItemSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(datamodel);
ItemSimilarity similarity = new CityBlockSimilarity(datamodel);
```

Then I pass the DataModel and ItemSimilarity into a GenericItemBasedRecommender and call the `mostSimilarItems()` function and pass it into a list.

```
ItemBasedRecommender irecommender = new GenericItemBasedRecommender(datamodel, similarity);
List<RecommendedItem> irecommendations = irecommender.mostSimilarItems(item, amount);
```

The `CityBlockSimilarity()` class worked great on a small data set, but as soon as I switched to a large data set it was no longer reliable.

Is there a different class I need to implement to return recommendations for an item based off of other items that users also have in common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out the class I needed to implement was the `TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity` class. Once I changed this, I was seeing the results I wanted to see.

```
ItemSimilarity similarity = new TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(datamodel);
```

I was able to leave everything else the same and it worked great! Here is a link to the [TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity class](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout-0.7-cdh4.3.2/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity.html) if you want to read more about it.

Comment: Afaik, Tanimato is for boolean preferences. Changing recommender to GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender may also increase results.

Comment: @Turcia - Great, thanks! I've put that in and the couple tests I ran showed the exact same results but I'll keep checking it out!